# Trying to send an email through an iphone app and getting an error using MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 8

Tags: email, ios-simulator, ios8, xcode6

I imported the MessageUI.h class and implemented the function in MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate.
I was following the tutorial on : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-101-send-email-iphone-app/

I am currently using Xcode 6.0.1 and iOS SDK 8.0 to build and run the app on the simulator. The issue is:

On running the app in the simulator, I get the following error

`2014-09-26 03:39:07.687 SendMessage[44465:2674263] Mail cancelled
2014-09-26 03:39:07.743 SendMessage[44465:2673753] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 3.)" UserInfo=0x7fe873e01d30 {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
2014-09-26 03:39:25.172 SendMessage[44465:2674263] <MFMailComposeRemoteViewController: 0x7fe873c389e0> timed out waiting for fence barrier from com.apple.MailCompositionService`

Any suggestions on what should be done to get this working?

Comment: The simulator doesn't have the Mail app or a way to setup mail accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known error in the simulator. It does not appear when you run on a device. So, try it on a device and if it runs normally, then you should be ok.